# Docker-compose and Xvfb incompatibility?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, capybara-webkit, xvfb

Since I installed Capybara-webkit, I can't launch my specs with docker compose. The next command stays on hold:

```
$ docker-compose run web xvfb-run -a bundle exec rspec
```

I thought I have a problem with Capybara-webkit, so I created a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510512/launching-capybara-webkit-on-a-dockerized-rails-5-app) and [an issue on the repo](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/1019), but it seems it's more a pb of interaction between docker-compose and xvfb.

If I do first

```
$ docker-compose run web bash
```

then

```
$ xvfb-run -a bundle exec rspec spec
```

it works fine. I have no clue.

**Edit 31/08/17**

As requested, here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXXXX
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app_dir
      - app-gems:/usr/local/bundle
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
  redis:
    driver: local
  app-gems:
    driver: local
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.4.1

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
  build-essential \
  libpq-dev \
  nodejs \
  xvfb \
  qt5-default \
  libqt5webkit5-dev \
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
  gstreamer1.0-tools \
  gstreamer1.0-x

RUN mkdir /app_dir
WORKDIR /app_dir

ADD Gemfile* /app_dir/

RUN bundle install

COPY . .
```

Comment: Joe Ferris, creator of Capybara-webkit, gave me three leads:  


- the default shell

- stdin

- interactive vs non-interactive shell invocations.

Comment: Did you try this `docker-compose run web /bin/bash -c "xvfb-run -a bundle exec rspec"`. You can also try another one and see if it works. You can also try another version `docker-compose run web /bin/bash -c "exec xvfb-run -a bundle exec rspec"`

Comment: Both gave me the same response : `ERROR: Cannot start service web: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin\": permission denied"`

Comment: There was a typo, please check the edited comment

Comment: Both stayed on hold, exactly like my original command :(

Comment: Post your `docker-compose` file

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Would need a sample git repo that i can use to debug this, without that it would be tough to understand

Comment: A while ago but any news in the subject?

Comment: we made it work, but few month later we changed our mind and start using chromedriver instead of capybara-webkit. It just work better and don't need Qt. The capybara-webkit team seems to hesitate to kep maintening it.

Answer (score 3):

In docker-compose.yml

```
command: ./start.sh
```

And in start.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
xvfb-run "run whatever"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Posting comments as answer since I need formatting**

Can you try changing below

```
command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
```

to

```
entrypoint: xvfb-run -a bundle exec rspec
```

and try `docker-compose up`

Also if that doesn't work then try adding `tty: true` to the service